# Why is this AJAX call to the correct php script not returning anything?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I posted a similar question earlier, just I did not realize that the code I put had an obvious bug in it (not supplying the data) which I new existed. Now I am redoing it with that because I am still having the problem.

I have this AJAX:

```
function sendMail(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../prestige-auto/php/sendMail.php",
                data: {"message" : $('#contactMessage').html(),
                         "email" : $('#contactEmail').val(),
                         "name" : $('#contactName').val()},
                success: function(result){
                    if (result == 'success') {
                        alert(result);
                    } else {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

$('#submitContact').click(function(){
        sendMail();
    })
```

and this PHP:

```
<?php

$trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);

$message = $trimmed['message'];
$email = $trimmed['email'];
$name = $trimmed['name'];

if (empty($message)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if (empty($email)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if (empty($name)) {
    $message = FALSE;
}

if ($message && $email && $name){

    $body = "From: $name.\n \n $message";

    mail(/*some email*/, 'Website Contact Form Submission', $body, "From: $email");

    echo ('success');

}

echo($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);

?>
```

All the html elements defined exist. When I run it all that returns is a blank alert box (meaning that the PHP script did not print out success). Any idea why it is not sending the mail?

Comment: Not a solution, but if I make the `name` `email` and `message` variables static (not from a form as you didn't provide the markup) and call the `sendMail` function onload, it sends the mail and outputs the response just as expected. Something else must be causing the issue.

Comment: @Mahdi.Montgomery Ok, that was my suspicion. I think it is something with my web server. Thanks.

Comment: does `var_dump($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);` not return at least the type of variable (string in this) and the size of the string?

Comment: @ace It doesn't return anything at all. That is what has stumped me.

Comment: Hmmm. that's indeed strange, try replacing `url: "../prestige-auto/php/sendMail.php"` with the absolute path instead. And just to be sure, use Firebug (or anything that checks ajax response/request) to check if it's a 200 or 404 or 500 request. ah, silly me, it must be a 200 right because you get the `alert` to show. hmmm

Comment: What kind of element is `#submitContact`? Perhaps you need to prevent 'normal' submission with `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`?

Comment: @ace it does the exact same thing, and yes it is a 200

Comment: @karim79 it's a button. The default is prevented already.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't exit after echoing out the `'success'` - PHP hasn't stopped processing yet, so it just continues to the next line, and renders out `echo($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);` as well.

This means your JS test is comparing `success` with `success$message $email $name`, which is always false.

If you want to stop processing, you have two choices: either `exit` or `die` (don't do this), or wrap the rest of the code in an else tag, like this:

```
if ($message && $email && $name){

    $body = "From: $name.\n \n $message";

    mail(/*some email*/, 'Website Contact Form Submission', $body, "From: $email");

    echo ('success');

} else {

    echo($message.' '.$email.' '.$name);

}
```

Also, make sure you **don't end your PHP scripts with `?>` !**  This almost always leads to problems later where the PHP script renders out some unwanted white space at the end, which would also fail.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `array_map('trim', $_POST)` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php#96246

Answer (score 0):

check ajax response first to see if there is any error occurs.